# Git branching practice with future and upcoming code comingled

Tags: git

My team is using GIT with a typical develop - release - master branch setup. All feature branches are created off develop and the release branch is created off develop.

But instead of merging feature branches back to develop they want to first commit it to a *future code* branch where all code resides - stuff for next prod release and everything else.

This creates a problem because sometimes there will be merge conflicts when pushing stuff to *future code*; and when that happens you'll have to merge with the tip of *future code* to resolve it and then you'll have future stuff in your branch.

They've come up with several ways to keep the original branch from being polluted with future stuff. But I believe any way (keeping an original copy, keeping track of commits to cherry pick, etc..) is not an elegant solution to this.

I believe there should be no future code branch and if you want to show QA early then you run a build off a feature branch - no future code branch.

Are there other approaches that people have used successfully don't twist GIT into a knot?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds equivalent to splitting the single develop branch into an unstable work-in-progress branch and a (more) stable integration branch.

Whether feature branches start from the (last) stable integration build, or from the tip of unstable, shouldn't make much difference except for testing that feature in isolation.

> This creates a problem because sometimes there will be merge conflicts when pushing stuff to future code; and when that happens you'll have to merge with the tip of future code to resolve it and then you'll have future stuff in your branch

You don't have to merge back to the feature branch to resolve this, you can just resolve the merge normally.

> I believe there should be no future code branch and if you want to show QA early then you run a build off a feature branch - no future code branch.

So no opportunity to run integration tests in QA before the final merge from feature back to develop? That can be fine, it just means develop will be relatively unstable.

> there other approaches that people have used successfully don't twist GIT into a knot?

Merge conflicts aren't twisting anything into a knot - you just resolve them and move on.

Comment: Ok, so I commit my feature branch into "future code" and there is a merge conflict. I merge with the tip of "future code" into my feature branch to resolve it and then pull in everything else from "future code". Now if all looks good then how do I get it back to develop where I create my release branch without pulling everything else in from future code?

Comment: "Commit my feature branch into future code" - what does that mean? You commit _on_ your feature branch. When you merge your feature branch to future/unstable/whatever, you're merging _from_ the feature branch, not onto it. If you never want to promote a commit on that future/unstable branch to stable/develop, you can merge your feature branch there directly. It's really _really_ unclear whether you know which direction your merges are happening, what `git commit` does, etc.

Comment: Apologies, I misspoke. When I merge from my feature branch to "future code" there could be a merge conflict. In order to resolve it don't I have to get the latest from "future code" first? And if I do that don't I pull in everything from "future code"? Eventually, I want to promote the commit from the feature branch to develop -- after QA takes a look and signs off on it. I won't be able to accomplish that unless I push everything from "future code" onto develop or unless I've got some other version of my feature branch that hasn't been merged with future code.

Comment: No, when a merge cannot complete automatically, you can just manually resolve it (or use mergetool), and then add & complete the merge. You don't need to merge backwards first. Read the [git-merge documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts).

Comment: Got it, thanks. I wasn't aware that I could merge a feature onto another branch without performing a backward merge. Now I can safely do that (without deleting the feature branch), have QA look, and when they sign off I can then merge it back to the "develop" branch. This allows me to keep using the "git-flow" approach that I'm used to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issues you face with going straight from `develop` branch is you have the added complex of people adding commits which QA may not want in the build. Also there no solid flow or a way for if QA come back with a bug for you to checkout the branch and play around with it (as developers commit a lot daily).

If you give a build from the developers local feature branch, things start to repeat and QA can not handle the amount of builds they get. We tend to supply builds every week with a lot of features in it together.

I tend to stick to a solid structure

```
ReleaseCandidate - this is where live code is
BetaCandidate - this is where 'future' code lives
DeveloperMaster - this is where every developer puts there code in
```

What this gives you is:

- DeveloperMaster can only be merged into BetaCandidate
- BetaCandidate can only be merged into ReleaseCandidate
- Developers do all there commits in DeveloperMaster

When a build is needed a dedicated developer merges all of the features into BetaCandidate and gives a build to QA. QA come back and 3 out of 50 new features have failed, you now cherry pick and delete those commits from BetaCandidate and merge BetaCandidate into ReleaseCandidate and release it.

The developer then still has his old change in DeveloperMaster and can address the bug and this feature goes into the next beta build.

If the feature needs to be fixed before the release the developer does the change in DeveloperMaster and cherry picks that commit into BetaCandidate.

You have this solid git flow which allows nothing to go backwards only forwards.

Comment: Ok, so you cherrypick to build your release candidate. And what if you fail a long-running feature branch in ReleaseCandidate that spans several Sprints and has, let's say, 50 commits. You cherry pick those out?

Comment: If someone fails in beta you can either A) fix it or B) remove the commits from beta and address this is developer in the next sprint. You then merge BetaCandidate into ReleaseCandidate and that is that. If you find a bug later on in ReleaseCandidate surely its a hot fix straight into ReleaseCandidate to resolve the issue and then you do that fix in DeveloperMaster and BetaCandidate.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Your approach means that developers should at least be knowledgeable enough to perform cherry picking. In my experience not all developers know how, especially UI developers. Also, your approach should probably necessitate prefixing all commits with a JIRA task # so you can easily find all commits associated with a feature.

Comment: Ticket ID really help on visibility of tickets so yes I would heavily advise that